# Populating third item from list into grid view?

Tags: android, gridview

Hi I Have Passed list of item in that i want to populate only the third item from that list ,i tried but only first list item 's third element only populated .

```
if(row == null) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
  row = inflater.inflate(nlayoutResourceId, parent, false);
  holder = new ViewHolder();
  holder.image=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Image);
  row.setTag(holder); 
} 

MediaAnswerGridItemContainer ClientAnswer = data.get(position);
```

Comment: post some code of what you have done

Comment: if(row == null)
  {
   LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
   row = inflater.inflate(nlayoutResourceId, parent, false);
   holder = new ViewHolder();
   holder.image=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.Image);
   row.setTag(holder);
  }


  MediaAnswerGridItemContainer ClientAnswer = data.get(position);

Comment: if i change no of columns form 1 to 2 means it wont insert picture

Comment: image is overriding the previously taken image please tell solutio

Comment: what do you mean by "only first list item 's third element only populated"?